# For $H \leq G$, showing that $N_G(H)/C_G(H) \leq \text{Aut}(H)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

This question probably has a very simple answer!

I'm trying to understand the proof of the following result from Dummit and Foote, 3ed:

[image: cor4.4.15]

Here is the proposition referenced:

[image: prop4.4.13]

I don't understand the part where Proposition 13 is applied "with $N_G(H)$ playing the role of $G$".  Wouldn't this only give me that $N_G(H)/C_{N_G(H)}(H)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\text{Aut}(H)$?  How does $C_G(H)$ appear?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You are right, but if $g$ is in $C_G(H)$, then *a fortiori* $g$ is in $N_G(H)$, so $C_G(H) = C_{N_G(H)}(H)$.  (You should write out the definitions of the two sets that I'm claiming are equal and convince yourself that they are the same.)

Comment: $C_G(H)$ is certainly contained in $N_G(H).$ Hence $C_{N_G(H)}(H)$ is the same as $C_G(H).$

Comment: Thank you Geoff and William.  It is now very clear that $C_X(H) = C_G(H) \cap X$, and so $C_{N_G(H)}(H) = C_G(H) \cap N_G(H) = C_G(H)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just so the question isn't "unanswered"...

Thanks to the comments left by William DeMeo and Geoff Robinson.

We have $C_X(H) = C_G(H) \cap X$ for any $X$, so $$C_{N_G(H)}(H) = C_G(H) \cap N_G(H) = C_G(H)$$ since $C_G(H) \subseteq N_G(H)$.